# s3cmd configuration file for google cloud storage

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, s3cmd

How can I configure s3cmd configuration file (.s3cfg) to connect to google cloud storage buckets?

I feel that below variables may be related to the issue:

```
access_key
secret_key
host_base
host_bucket
service_path
```

Comment: This should have the general idea for setup: https://www.betterservers.com/system/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=53

Comment: Thanks. But it does not show the values of google cloud storage as it gives a general idea as you have mentioned.

Comment: Alternatively you can try https://github.com/minio/mc - which supports Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: @harshavardhana Thank. However, it does not support GnuPG encryption

Comment: Nope it doesn't - are you talking about uploading with encryption? or just configuration file needs to be encrypted?

Comment: @Harshavardhana Thanks again. I'm talking about uploading with encryption

Comment: @Basem - no we do not . The best way to achieve that is encrypt locally and **stream to server**

`$ tar -cvf - /home | aescrypt -e -p apples - | mc pipe storage.googleapis.com/yourbucket/your-encryptedobject.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Interoperability settings to create the key pair.

https://bitmovin.com/docs/encoding/faqs/how-can-i-create-access-secret-keys-for-google-cloud-storage

The other parameters are (from the same settings menu):

```
host_base = storage.googleapis.com
host_bucket = %(bucket).storage.googleapis.com
```

I did not need to use `service_path`